# Connection Failure: Status code unavailable

Tags: coldfusion, google-geocoding-api

I am using google api with a test key

```
<cfhttp method="post" url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?key=AIzaSyAoMhyMMfSvs1Z9xp9fNiBt9ogpryCQZNQ"
result="googlejson" throwonerror="true">
  <cfhttpparam name="address" type="URL" value="1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#googlejson#" />

<cfabort>
```

"Connection Failure: Status code unavailable" occurred while running above code in local system but getting response from postman. I am using CF16.
   [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3cLY.png)

Comment: How woiuld any one know which API yoy have run and what is the issue

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion are you running? It could possibly be related to your keystore not having the certificate for maps.googleapis.com.

Comment: @Sree , can you share the complete dump result ?

Answer (score 3):

I got the following output when I ran the script in my local environment (CF2016).

[image]

It gave me desired output. So there should not be any error when you run it locally. I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for? Which version CF you are using?

Comment: I am using CF16, I am getting "Connection Failure: Status code unavailable
" while running this code